# How to put a custom .psd button in android layout?

Tags: android, psd

I have a `.psd` file and I want to use it as a button in my app. I also have the pressed version of that button. How can I put it in the layout and make it to show the pressed state when the button is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as my knowledge goes android does not support .psd. Convert it to a jpg or png and you will be golden.

Here is a list and more information on what formats android supports 
https://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

And here is a quick way to change the button:

You need two images (image1 and image2) in the drawable folder and then change between them like this

```
Button b1;
ImageView iw;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

   b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
   b1.setOnClickListener(this); 

   iw = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (v == b1)
    {
        iw.setImageResource(R.drawable.image2);
    }

}
```

}

Hope this helps a bit